# FFMpegWriter not using the bitrate specified? Animation is very blurry

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am using `matplotlib`'s `FunAnimation` as well as `FFMpegWriter` to try to write a simulation animation to a file. I'd like to save a high quality version of it, but when I increase the `bitrate` value of the writer, the actual bitrate of the `.mp4` it creates seems to increase in discrete steps up to a fairly low value after which it doesn't increase any more whatsoever.

My code is roughly:

```
dpi = 96
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width/dpi, height/dpi), dpi=dpi)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, myAnimation, frames=100, interval=1, blit=True)
writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=10, bitrate=<some number>)
anim.save('MyAnimation.mp4', writer=writer)
```

The animation is only 200x200px so I feel like it shouldn't be a problem to have a high quality video, but I can't seem to get a high enough bitrate. For the following bitrates specified in my code, the actual bitrate shown in the files properties are:

```
BR In Code   => Actual BR (kbps)
-1 / None    => 13
100          => 58
1000         => 76
10000        => 76
```

The bitrate doesn't seem to track very well at all, and won't go above `76kbps` at all. The video is still badly blurry at this bitrate.

What do I need to do to increase the bitrate or else the quality of the video file?

Alternatively, is there a better video format/writer to use for this purpose? Specifically one that is broadly supported so I could embed it in a website or upload it to YouTube or something like that.

**Edit:**

To be more specific about the issue, neighboring pixels are being blended together, resulting in a blurry look. The following imgur album shows several examples with different settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCO9q.jpg

These include the view in the figure window from `plt.show()`, default bitrate, a "high" bitrate, and something else I just tried which was to increase the dpi. While the results are much nicer it also nearly doubled the execution time so I'd like to avoid it.

It seems silly to have to upscale what is effectively "pixel art" in order for it to look good, but I guess this is an artifact of the signal processing approach mpeg uses, which is why I suspect a different file format might be the best solution for small framed animations like this. If I wanted to do a 1920*1080 animation the blurring would probably be less of an issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "high quality"?  Are you seeing details get lost?  In a 200x200 pixel image, you're never going to get much detail, Such an image, even at minimal compression, will never be very large.  Can you show us an example?

Comment: I've edited with more detail + screenshots, hopefully clarifies it

Comment: MPEG's _purpose_ is to quantize a high-bitrate image down to something lower-quality; it was designed for camera output, not line drawings, and animations hit its corner cases pretty hard. Have you considered creating an animated GIF instead, or using a format like MNG that's otherwise more suitable for pixel art?

Comment: I have to be honest, I don't see any difference between the `plt.show` result and the movie frames.  As you say, you may need to create higher resolution source images.

Comment: (higher-resolution source images do make sense here: MPEG breaks things down into blocks; you're going to have fewer problems when the details you care about aren't smallest than the smallest block size).

Comment: I have done previous animations with GIF but stopped using it because of its color limitations. I'll probably just go with an upscaled .mp4 for simplicity as uploading to youtube is, for now, the end goal. Unless I'm missing some lossless format that youtube supports.

Comment: Even just using 2x DPI worked surprisingly well and didn't compromise runtime too much, for anyone in the future.